# I am trying to only return items in an array that contain a matching key with a true value where the key comes from a separate array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, object, filter

### Brief example:

piece of state: `['youth', 'college'];`

event Object:

```
{ name: theEvent,
ageDivisions: {
    youth: true,
    middleSchool: true,
    highSchool: true,
    college: true
    open: false
},
}
```

#### What I want to accomplish

I want to filter through multiple event objects and only return when the event at least contains all the matching strings in the state array. this array is created based on what the user selects from the form (image Below)

[image: Form User Fills Out]

#### My approach so far:

So far my approach has been to turn the events age divisions parameter into an array of arrays that contain the key and the value. Positions 1 and 2 respectfully

##### Here is the code:

[codePenLink](https://codepen.io/WakyWayne/pen/wvmQXzW)

```js
if (filterParamaters.ageDivisions !== undefined && filterParamaters.ageDivisions.length != false) {


          let parsedEvents = events.data.map(({ attributes: event }) => {
            return {
              ...event,
              ...event.attributes,
              ageDivisions: JSON.parse(event.ageDivisions),
              eventStyles: JSON.parse(event.eventStyles),
            }
          })
          console.log({ parsedEvents });

          filteredEventss = parsedEvents.filter((event) => {
            // make event .attributes.ageDivisions object an array of key value pairs
            console.log({ eventThatWeAreFiltering: event });
            if ((event.ageDivisions !== undefined && event.ageDivisions !== null)) {
              let eventAgeDivisions = Object.entries(event.ageDivisions);
              console.log({ theAgifiedObject: eventAgeDivisions });
              // This maps through each object in the Object key value pair Array 
              // It might be easier to use map and just chang the array to only have the matching values
              let onlyTrueEventAgedivisions = eventAgeDivisions.map((ageDivision, index) => {
                console.log({ theAgeDivision: ageDivision[2] });
                if (ageDivision[2] === true) {
                  return [ageDivision[0], ageDivision[2]];
                } else {
                  return false;
                }
              })
              console.log({ theTrueEventAgedivisions: onlyTrueEventAgedivisions });
              
            }
          })
          console.log({ theFinishedFilteredevents: filteredEventss });
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I did was check if the `ageDivisions` existed in each object and if it does, run this `filterParameters.ageDivisions` list, checking if every property that you want to be true is set to true .

```js
const result = parsedEvents.filter((e) => e.ageDivisions && filterParameters.ageDivisions.every(prop => e.ageDivisions[prop]))
console.log(result);
```

Comment: but every property will rarely be set to true. I think I wasn't clear in my question I have revised the question and added an image that might make it more clear what I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: This `filterParameters.ageDivisions.every(prop => e.ageDivisions[prop]))` is not every property inside ageDivisions in each object, its actually every prop inside your state list, where you gonna set your filters

Comment: I understand your solution now I was being foolish and doing it backward. your solution is beautiful compared to mine. Thank you if I wanted to make it so that I can return events that have at least one match would I just switch every with a different array method?

Comment: Sure! If you switch `every` by `some`, its gonna check if at least one filter is set to true. 